# Starting docker daemon on mac

Tags: macos, docker

I have run through StackOverflow and other questions / docs - including the official ones and still have not been able to start `docker`.  Given the latest info here are a couple of options tried:

```
$ docker daemon
`docker daemon` is not supported on Darwin. Please run `dockerd` directly
16:20:54/Applications $dockerd
-bash: dockerd: command not found
```

`docker-machine` also surfaces as an option but that is gone for some time.

So what is the canonical way to start the `docker` daemon?  If it matters I am on `Sierra` : and the `docker` is the latest downloaded today 12/12/17.

```
 $docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce
 API version:  1.34
 Go version:   go1.9.2
 Git commit:   1caf76c
 Built:        unknown-buildtime
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

It is also worrisome that the URI referred to starts with `unix`.  Is there some preparation and/or configuration step(s) I missed?

Comment: Do you not have a control icon in your top bar? That is where the start and restart commands reside for me at least

Comment: @benashby  No, i don't have the whale ;(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just try `open --background -a Docker`

Comment: I "stepped away" from this question and for some reason had not been notified of answers: just saw this now and confirmed it works.

Comment: how to stop docker from the command line on Mac Os?

Comment: this results with `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Docker.app with error -610.`

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the whale either.
I had to restart Docker this morning and used this:

/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: I can try and make the above clearer. Because Docker had not started, 
I started it manually from the terminal. 
I pasted the above line into the terminal and it restored the icon.